# Leaflet: Error working with more than one layer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, gis

I need to use two layer options on a few pages in my Vue project. I'm using the Leaflet.js  library to plot these maps, but I have a problem with zoom functionality when I switch between layers. I tried several solutions, but all seem to give the same problem, would it be a problem of `version 1.7.1` of the library? I would like help to work around this problem.

My Vue code:

```
<template>
  <div id="mapContainer" class="w-full h-full z-10"></div>
</template>

<script>
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css';

import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-draw';

// import translate from '../translate/MapDraw';

export default {
  props: {
    useUserLocation: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      map: null,
      coords: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getUserLocation() {
      try {
        const geolocation = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });

        this.coords = geolocation.coords;
      } catch (error) {
        this.coords = { latitude: -20.7542, longitude: -42.8819 };
      }
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    if (this.useUserLocation) {
      await this.getUserLocation();
    } else {
      this.coords = { latitude: -20.7542, longitude: -42.8819 };
    }

    const osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      minZoom: 6,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    });

    const satellite = L.tileLayer.wms(
      'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
      {
        minZoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 16,
        attribution:
          'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community',
      },
    );

    // Definição e plotagem do mapa
    this.map = L.map('mapContainer', {
      center: [this.coords.latitude, this.coords.longitude],
      zoom: 15,
      layers: [osm],
      attributionControl: true,
    });

    const baseMaps = {
      'Open Street Map': osm,
      'Visão de Satélite': satellite,
    };

    L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, { position: 'topright', collapsed: true }).addTo(this.map);

  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    if (this.map) {
      this.map.remove();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

[image: Errors thrown when zooming]

The proxys returned by data method don't work well with complex objects like map object returned by leaflet constructor, so we need to work without proxys.

A way to workarround this problem:

```
<script>
import { toRaw } from 'vue';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css';

import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-draw';

// import translate from '../translate/MapDraw';

export default {
  props: {
    useUserLocation: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      map: null,
      coords: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getUserLocation() {
      try {
        const geolocation = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });

        this.coords = geolocation.coords;
      } catch (error) {
        this.coords = { latitude: -20.7542, longitude: -42.8819 };
      }
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    if (this.useUserLocation) {
      await this.getUserLocation();
    } else {
      this.coords = { latitude: -20.7542, longitude: -42.8819 };
    }

    const osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      minZoom: 6,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    });

    const satellite = L.tileLayer.wms(
      'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
      {
        minZoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 16,
        attribution:
          'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community',
      },
    );

    // Definição e plotagem do mapa
    const map = L.map('mapContainer', {
      center: [this.coords.latitude, this.coords.longitude],
      zoom: 15,
      layers: [osm],
      attributionControl: true,
    });

    const baseMaps = {
      'Open Street Map': osm,
      'Visão de Satélite': satellite,
    };

    L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, { position: 'topright', collapsed: true }).addTo(this.map);

    this.map = map;
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    if (this.map) {
      toRaw(this.map).remove();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of Vue are you using?

Comment: I'm using vue 3

Comment: The proxy applied on the return of data method was the problem, the native function toRaw solved my question. Thanks!

Comment: @ErickFigueiredo You can answer your own question I think

Comment: @LeeGoddard I believe that unfortunately I don't have a minimal level to do this, but I will edit my question adding one solution. Thank you! ;-)